# Generating Schema Queries for setting up mysql DB locally for Spring MVC project

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am learning Spring MVC. I have a project which I want to set up in my system for making some enhancements in the project. Its a **Spring JPA Hibernate Maven based Project**. The issue is I dont have schema generation queries for this project.

**Can anyone tell me how can I generate schema creation queries from the hbm file of hibernate for setting up the db for this project.**

Note:My database is Mysql 5.0

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code to which will generate .sql file which contains DB creation queries or you can set `"hbm2ddl.auto"` at `create mode` which will generate all the tables

```
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    SchemaExport se = new SchemaExport(cfg);
    se.setDelimiter("\n#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    se.setOutputFile("E:\\BackUP\\DB.sql");
    se.create(true, true);// create(boolean script, boolean export)
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer. We can do this using maven plugin- hibernate3-maven-plugin. Here is the link with complete details:
http://www.celinio.net/techblog/?p=1125